# Is the US more tolerant of failure than other cultures?

Tags: united-states, sociology

I've come across several sources claiming that the US is more tolerant of trial-and-error than other cultures:

- (*The Black Swan* by Nassim Nicholas Taleb) "American culture encourages the process of failure, unlike the cultures of Europe and Asia where failure is met with stigma and embarrassment."
- ([a BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-20041320)) "The US has a culture tolerant of failure, driven by individual passion." (Implied contrast with the situation in China.)
- ([a book review of *The Upside of Down* by Megan McArdle](http://www.nationalreview.com/article/370549/failing-well-american-way-michael-barone)) "America succeeds because Americans fail and forgive." "The U.S. has the most accessible bankruptcy laws in the world."

I found [a single academic article](http://www.cbr.cam.ac.uk/pdf/WP334.pdf) on this topic (from the University of Cambridge), which has a more nuanced view, distinguishing between "failure tolerance" and "second chancing". Are there any other credible sources that discuss the attitude towards failure in different cultures?

Comment: Some anecdotal evidence: http://www.nytimes.com/2014/11/09/business/wearing-your-failures-on-your-sleeve.html

Comment: As there is no proper answer after long time, I can provide some anecdotal evidence: yes, at least in Eastern Europe this is true (I live there). The thinking is that if you fail, you are likely to fail again, not that you have learned a lesson and are less likely to fail again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [OECD (2013), “Culture: Attitude toward failure”, in Entrepreneurship at a
Glance 2013, OECD Publishing](http://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/industry-and-services/entrepreneurship-at-a-glance-2013/culture-attitude-toward-failure_entrepreneur_aag-2013-26-en), United States has an adult belief ratio exceeding 80% for failed entrepreneurs to be given a second chance. In most countries, a large majority of adults believe that entrepreneurs who fail should be given a “second chance”. The ratio is around or above 90% in Brazil, China, Greece, Ireland, Korea, Spain and Sweden, and exceeds 80% in several other countries including the Russian Federation and the United States. Comparing answers in 2012 with those provided in 2009 suggests that in many countries the positive attitudes relating to a ’second chance’ might have been reinforced by the recent financial crisis, i.e. people have become more sympathetic towards difficulties faced by entrepreneurs.